# DRF: UpdateAPI > 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, jwt

I am trying to create an UpdateAPI to update my model. I need to comply with this [API schema](https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide#an-example-update-api).

I have tried the following:

**api.py**

```py
class AlarmstichworteUpdateApi(ApiErrorsMixin, APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    class InputSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        updated = serializers.DateTimeField()
        name = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)
        class Meta:
            model = AlarmstichworteConfig
            fields = (
                '__all__'
            )

    def put(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.InputSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        update_alarmstichwort(id=id, **serializer.validated_data)

        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

**services.py**

```py
def update_alarmstichwort(
    *,
    id: int, 
    updated: datetime,
    name: str,
    ) -> AlarmstichworteConfig:

    alarmstichwort = alarmstichwort_by_id(id=id).update(
        name=name,
        updated=updated,
    )
    # alarmstichwort.full_clean()
    alarmstichwort.save()

    return alarmstichwort
```

**selector.py**

```py
def alarmstichwort_by_id(*, id, filters=None):
    return AlarmstichworteConfig.objects.filter(id=id)
```

However, I have the problem that this does not work. When I do it this way, I get the error:

> ```
>   File "D:\04-Dev\project\{...}\services.py",
>    line 48, in update_alarmstichwort
>     alarmstichwort.save()
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'
> ```

Can you help me or tell me what the error is? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [**`.update(…)`** method [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) returns the number of updated records, not (list of) a records, so you should omit the `.save()` part:

```
def update_alarmstichwort(
    *,
    id: int, 
    updated: datetime,
    name: str,
    ):

    alarmstichwort = alarmstichwort_by_id(id=id).update(
        name=name,
        updated=updated,
    )
```

If you want to retrieve the item itself and return the (updated) item, you can work with:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def update_alarmstichwort(
    *,
    id: int, 
    updated: datetime,
    name: str,
    ) -> AlarmstichworteConfig:

    alarmstichwort = get_object_or_404(alarmstichwort_by_id(id=id))
    alarmstichwort.name = name
    alarmstichwort.updated = updated
    alarmstichwort.save(update_fields=['name', 'updated'])
    return alarmstichwort
```